# Pymongo read my variable as licteral, also if i write with dollar $

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

the problem is easy, but i cant understand where i'm wrong:

I want to duplicate a field:

```
client = MongoClient(uri)
mydb = client["tesi_gazzette"]
gazzette_table = mydb["gazzette"]

gazzette_table.update_one(
    {},
    {'$set':
        {
            'codicerelazionale': '$uri'
        }
    }
)
```

but the result is:

[image]

Comment: Use `'codicerelazionale': uri` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going crazy!

Comment: Ups... no.
uri is a variable of my code, but i want to copy the value in the mongo document

Comment: Oh, you mean the document has a field named `uri`, and you want to set the field `codicerelazionale` to the same value as `uri`?

Comment: Yes! I solved with the code above

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
   gazzette_table.update_one(
        {},
        [
            {"$set": {"name": '$uri'}}
        ]
    )
```